# onCompletion in Android not picking up end of Media Player track

Tags: android, eclipse

I realise I am probably missing something obvious, but basically I have created a MediaPlayer which will play a track and at the end of it I want the media player to stop, reset and display the Seekbar back to zero, however when it gets to the end of the track, the onCompletion method does not seem to be working - basically the seekbar does not go back to zero. The seekbar is updating fine normally, so I am pretty sure it is nothing to do with the method for updating the seekbar and is to do with the onCompletion. Any advice please?

public class RelaxPlayer extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private Utilities utils;

    private MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_relax_player);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    // Mediaplayer
    myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); 
    myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); // 



    myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(RelaxPlayer.this, R.raw.bounce);


    Button myButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                if(myMediaPlayer!=null){
                    myMediaPlayer.pause();
                    //add code to change button text
                }
            } else{
                if(myMediaPlayer!=null){

            myMediaPlayer.start();
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);
            updateProgressBar();
            //add code to change text
                }
        }
            //more code that I won't copy here...but later
          @Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

   myMediaPlayer.pause();

   myMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

   songProgressBar.setProgress(0);// this then calls method which will update the seek bar
   updateProgressBar();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the media player with the line:

```
 myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(RelaxPlayer.this, R.raw.bounce);
```

So the setOnCompletionListener is for a different media player instance.

You probably want:

```
    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bounce);
    myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    Button myButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```